# navigationBar .tintColor with UIDocumentPickerViewController (Document Picker)?

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickervc

I am using Swift 2 in Xcode 7.0 beta 6

*Long story short*, I am trying to work out how to set  `.navigationBar.barStyle` and `navigationBar.tintColor` when using a document picker to access iCloud - i.e. a `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

I have tried e.g. :

```
/...
documentPicker.navigationController!.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
documentPicker.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
/...
```

---

For example. Here I have a view controller embedded within a navigation controller:

[image]

In `MyNavigationController` I can set the `.barStyle` and `.tintStyle` as follows:

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    }
}
```

So `.tintStyle` is orange as follows:

[image]

iCloud is enabled and `FirstViewController` conforms to `UIDocumentPickerDelegate`. The bar button calls an `IBAction` function as shown here in the code for `FirstViewController`:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    // ...
    @IBAction func importDocument(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.text"], inMode: UIDocumentPickerMode.Import)
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen
        documentPicker.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender
        self.presentViewController(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

    func documentPicker(controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAtURL url: NSURL) {
        // ...
    }

    func documentPickerWasCancelled(controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That works. The document picker loads as expected:

[image]

BUT. For the sake of working out how to do this, I want the menu item "Done" to be orange. Like the previous.

I have tried adding the following code to the `@IBAction` as follows:

```
//...
documentPicker.navigationController!.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
documentPicker.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
self.presentViewController(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
//...
```

That doesn't work because at this point `documentPicker.navigationController` is `nil`.

Can anyone tell me how or where in the cycle I can access `documentPicker.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor`?

Or perhaps I am missing something and there is some other way of changing the menu color?

Or perhaps I should be looking to create a custom navigation controller - and a custom document picker view controller. Then in theory I would be able to access a relevant `viewDidLoad`. I tried that but realised that I would then also need a custom version of the `UIDocumentPickerDelegate` protocol. There must surely be an easier solution (and I had doubts as to whether that would be allowed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can alter navigationBar default tint color via `UIAppearance`:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
```

Comment: This will change whole application tint color can we change just documentViewController tint color

Answer (score 1):

**swift 3,4 and xcode 9+** :

```
documentPicker.view.tintColor = .orange
```

Comment: its changing view items tint color not bar button tint color.

Comment: I know but in document picker there are no navigation bar ,
items are subviews of view so it resolves the problem

Comment: Naah it's not working . View tint color will apply on it's subview. Above answer works fine.

Comment: my code works for me not above answer , may be it is different in IOS version , if you found the answer why tell me

Comment: Using this approach will change the tint for the tab bar, search bar, and navigation bar within the document picker.

Comment: For me, this solution only worked but the issue I am facing is at first the Document Picker Cancel button color did not change but after first attempt in every attempt it changes properly.

Comment: UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDocumentBrowserViewController.self]).tintColor = nil work for me